# Enviar datos por post desde JQuery a Controller Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy tratando de enviar unos datos con JQuery o AJax a un controller al store en laravel pero no lo logro aun lo echo muchas veces en otros lenguajes pero en laravel no se como por el token y la url y el archivo js esta en una hoja propia NO esta dentro del html.

Mi codigo es el siguiente

html head

```
 <meta name="ruta" content="{{ url('/movies') }}">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ Session::token() }}">
<script>
var urlmovies = "{{ url('/movies') }}";
</script>
```

hoja de js

```
function registrarPelicula() {

    console.log(urlmovies);
    console.log($('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
    console.log($('meta[name="ruta"]').attr('content'));

    var nombrepelicula = $('#nombrepelicula').val();
    var descripcion = $('#descripcion').val();
    var token = '{{csrf_token()}}';
    var data = { nombrepelicula: nombrepelicula, descripcion: descripcion, _token: token };

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: urlmovies,
        data: data,
        success: function(msg) {
            alert("Se ha realizado el POST con exito " + msg);
        }
    });

    $.post(urlmovies, { nombrepelicula: nombrepelicula, descripcion: descripcion, _token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') });



}
```

errores en la consola del navegador con alguna de las dos opciones.

```
Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
Uncaught TypeError: $.post is not a function
```

Comment: Debe faltar incluir la libreria jQuery, o es una version reducida (jQuery slim?), revisa https://code.jquery.com/ para incluir el archivo JS adecuado

Comment: El que he usado es este <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script> ese lo uso en php para que me permita enviar los datos por post desde js.

Comment: La console te muestra que falla en cargar la funcion de JQuery, prueba en el navegador haciendo una consulta simple como let elem = $(".una-clase") a ver si que error te manda